# Rendering view for infinitely nested comments in AngularJS [infinite digest cycle]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, recursion

I'm currently trying to infinitely nested comments (and their replies), similar to Reddit.

I currently have a large structure of the general form:

```
[
    {
        comment_id: 1
        comment_text: "root1"
        replies:[
            {
                 comment_id: 2
                 comment_text: "reply1",
                 replies: [
                      ....
                 ]
            }   
        ]
    },
    {
        comment_id: 3
        comment_text: "root2"
        replies:[
              ...
        ]
    },
]
```

Since all comments follow a general `div template` and their replies are just `margin-left:50px;` additional, I followed this tutorial that uses recursive `ng-repeat` and recursively includes the template and their replies

http://benfoster.io/blog/angularjs-recursive-templates

So my code is like this in HTML:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="commentTree">
    <div>
        <img ng-src="{{comment.author.avatar}}" style="height:50px;">
        <a ng-href="/user/{{comment.author.user_id}}">{{comment.author.username}}</a>
        <br/>
        <small><strong>Posted</strong> <span am-time-ago="comment.date_posted"></span></small>
        <p>
            {{comment.comment_text}}
        </p>
        <span style="margin-right:5px;">
            <a href ng-click="comment.show_reply_box = true;" ng-show="!comment.show_reply_box">
            Reply
            </a>
            <div ng-show="comment.show_reply_box">
                <textarea ng-model="comment.possible_reply" class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="Write your reply here..."></textarea>
                <span style="margin-right:10px;"><button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="vm.post_comment(comment, comment.possible_reply)">Comment</button></span>
                <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="comment.show_reply_box = false;">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </span>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div ng-repeat="comment in comment.replies" ng-include="'commentTree'" style="margin-left:50px;">
    </div>
</script>

    <div ng-repeat="comment in comment.replies" ng-include="'commentTree'" style="margin-left:50px;">
    </div>
```

However, the problem is that `ng-repeat` is extremely badly optimized and I am getting `infdig` error cycles due to the nested `ng-repeat`s I am having. This is weird, as I'm certain it's not being caused by the number of comments I have, but rather the fact that I have nested `ng-repeats`. However, it does provide extremely helpful data-binding.  I would like ot continue using `ng-repeat` or at least maintaining two-way data binding in some form, but avoid this `infdig` cycle. Does anyone have any ideas on what the best practices are infinitely nested comments or how to optimize AngularJS for this?

Comment: Hi Philip, Has the answer I gave below helped you at all? Best, Dewd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are missing the `ng-if` wrapping the `ng-repeat` within your template.

change:

```
 <div ng-repeat="comment in comment.replies" ng-include="'commentTree'" style="margin-left:50px;">
</div>
```

to:

```
<div ng-if="comment.replies.length">
    <div ng-repeat="comment in comment.replies" ng-include="'commentTree'" style="margin-left:50px;">           
    </div>
</div>
```

Note, this assumes an empty array for replies if there are no replies. If there are no replies and an empty reply array isn't added, the code should be:

```
<div ng-if="comment.replies">
    <div ng-repeat="comment in comment.replies" ng-include="'commentTree'" style="margin-left:50px;">           
    </div>
</div>
```

Example: https://plnkr.co/edit/B99uT2VBAKwpHzevjqip?p=preview